# targeting live_videos using facebook graph API 2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a Live_Video following the instructions i've found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts?locale=en_US#geotarget
with the API 2.8 using the following parameters:
planned_start_time=1512583432 and
targeting="countries": [ "CH" ]

got the following response:
    {
      "id": "1694620797236299",
      "stream_url": "rtmp://live-api-a.facebook.com:80/rtmp/1694620797236299?ds=1&a=ATg9BhMPftTTsfv3",
      "secure_stream_url": "rtmps://live-api-a.facebook.com:443/rtmp/1694620797236299?ds=1&a=ATg9BhMPftTTsfv3",
      "stream_secondary_urls": [
      ],
      "secure_stream_secondary_urls": [
      ]
    }

so, everything seems fine, BUT:

How do i check that the vision of the video is actually restricted to 
Switzerland ?
Where is this info stored ?
How do I retrieve it ?

Thanks for the help.
greetings-
cp

Comment: I've forgot to mention that i didn't copy the notation  {"countries": [ "CH" ]} from the documentation because this is what i would get:   "message": "(#100) Invalid keys \"countries\" were found in param \"targeting\".",

Comment: You can't retrieve that information back AFAIK. If you edit it via the UI, I think you should see if the targeting was applied as intended. If you request the details of the video via API with an app access token, you should get an "Unsupported GET request" error - that would at least prove that it is not publicly available; for more accurate tests you would need access tokens from user in/out of the targeted country though, I think.

Answer (score 0):

through the UI:
there is a gear wheel on the top part of the post that 
responds to mouseOver with the geoblocking info of the livestreaming
If the livestreaming is blocked it reflects there.

Still working on getting the same info from the API ...